# How to extract audio from tokbox - what format?

Tags: audio, webrtc, wav, flac

TokBox uses WebRTC. 
How can I extract select (on demand) audio streams from a TokBox session? What format will the audio file be ... wav ... FLAC ... is there option?

Curious does wav format involve some royalty fees to Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

TokBox currently has an archiving service through which one would be able to record all the streams in a session and then extract the audio - below is the archiving API:
https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/archiving/